# How to resolve below query while we trying to upload and excel file from jsp

Tags: java, excel, file, file-upload

We are getting below error message while trying to access.

```
List items = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request);
```

error

```
11:10:35,558 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: 
the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream,content type 
header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Comment: Please paste your JSP, also check what is the Content-Type you mentioned in your jsp

Comment: If you used something in the lines of `<input type="file"` then you *must* have enc-type on the form tag as  : `<form action="...." method=".." enctype="multipart/form-data">`